# Genitiv mit Possessivartikel

Tags: possessive

Sehen Sie sich bitte diese Sätze an:

1. *Er hat in sein Vaters Bäckerei gearbeitet.*
2. *Er hat in seiner Vaters Bäckerei gearbeitet.*

Welcher Satz ist richtig? Können Sie bitte ein bisschen erzählen? Ich habe gedacht, das 1 richtig ist, aber jemand hat mir gesagt, dass 2 richtig ist. Aber ich verstehe es nicht. Müssen wir Genitiv zwei mal markieren? Einmal mit "**s**" in Sein Vater**s** und einmal mit "**er**" für das Wort "Bäckerei"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keiner der Sätze ist richtig. [Ein Blick in diese Tabelle](https://language-easy.org/german/grammar/pronouns/possessive/) zeigt, dass das korrekte Possesivpronomen *seines* lautet (Er, Genitiv).

Üblicherweise<sup>†</sup> würde man dann sagen:

> Er hat in der Bäckerei seines Vaters gearbeitet

Oder mit der von-Konstruktion

> Er hat in der Bäckerei von seinem Vater gearbeitet

Wobei der erste Satz stylistisch schöner ist (meine Meinung).

Um die Verwirrung zu nehmen, hier noch eine Analyse des Satzes:

> Peter<sub>1</sub> hat [in der Bäckerei]<sub>2</sub> gearbeitet
> <sub>1</sub>Subjekt (Nominativ)
> <sub>2</sub>adverbiale Ortsangabe (Dativ)

> Er<sub>1</sub> hat [in der Bäckerei]<sub>2</sub> [seines Vaters]<sub>3</sub> gearbeitet
> <sub>1</sub>Subjekt (Nominativ)
> <sub>2</sub>adverbiale Ortsangabe (Dativ)
> <sub>3</sub>Genitivobjekt (Nominativ: sein Vater)

<sup>†</sup>Wie phibsgabler in den Kommentaren korrekt bemerkt, ist es auch korrekt "Er hat in seines Vaters Bäckerei gearbeitet.", allerdings klingt dies ziemlich altmodisch und wird im Alltag eher nicht so ausgedrückt. Die Umordnung des Satzes ist allerdings **nicht** möglich mit der von-Konstruktion: <strike>Er hat in von seinem Vater der Bäckerei gearbeitet</strike>. Auch wenn man solche oder so ähnliche Konstruktionen zunehmend zu hören bekommt.

Comment: Dankeschön für Ihre Antwort! Ich bin eine A2.1 Studentin und das Genitiv kenne ich nicht jetzt so gut; (z.B. "seines" usw) aber ich habe eine alternative Konstruktion gelernt und Ihre Antwort habe ich verstanden! Danke!

Comment: _Er hat in seines Vaters Bäckerei gearbeitet_ wäre ebenfalls völlig korrekt, klingt aber absolut altmodisch.

Comment: Der Kontext könnte hier täuschen - wer arbeitet heute noch im Betrieb seines Vaters? "Er hat in Peters Band gespielt" klingt überhaupt nicht altmodisch und derartige Konstrukte hört man so häufig, dass man es gar nicht bemerkt und folglich bei Aussagen über die Häufigkeit leicht daneben liegen kann.

Comment: Dann gibt es noch die dialektale Variante mit Possessivpronomen + Dativ (nicht zur Nachahmung empfohlen): "Er hat in seinem Vater seiner Bäckerei gearbeitet".

Comment: @userunknown Ein kongruentes Beispiel wäre "Er hat in meines Bruders/Freundes Band gespielt." Das hat mit dem Betrieb des Vaters überhaupt nichts zu tun. Ich halte es auch heute nicht für unwahrscheinlich, dass der Sohn im Betrieb seines Vaters arbeitet.

Comment: Ja, und wieso sollte man nicht sagen: "Er hat in meines Bruders Band gespielt." Daran ist nichts altmodisch.

Comment: @user unknown: ich habe die Konstruktion noch nicht einmal gehört. In welcher Region sprechen Menschen denn so?

Comment: Überall, wo man Hochdeutsch spricht.

Comment: Anscheinend nicht, sonst wäre mir das schon untergekommen.